# Necesito saber el número de registro del último Insert PDO PHP Mysql

Tags: mysql, php7, pdo, insert, registro

Yo hago este insert, y tengo la columna autoincremental al terminar preciso saber el Nº que le a dado al registro

Mi código es este, funciona perfecto menos, $id = $conn->lastInsertId() que no me da ningún valor

```
    $rescab="INSERT INTO turf_carrr 
    ( idcarrr, dia, mes, anio, nrocarrr, 
    fecha, tipcarrr1, tipcarrr2, tipcarrr3, tipcarrr4 ,
    idubiccn , idubiccn2, estado, nombrcarrr, condicion, 
    distnc, temp, pista, estpista , hora, 
    nrocarrr2, oficial)  

    Values 
    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";

$hacerConsulta = $conn->prepare($rescab); // Se crea un objeto PDOStatement.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(1, $idcarrera  ); // Se asigna una variable para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(2, $dia); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(3, $mes); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(4, $anio); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(5, $nrocarrr); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(6, $feccar  ); // Se asigna una variable para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(7, $idtipcarrr1); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(8, $idtipcarrr2); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(9, $idtipcarrr3); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(10, $idtipcarrr4); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(11, $idubiccn); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(12, $idubiccn2); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(13, $estado); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(14, $nombrcarrr); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(15, $condi2); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(16, $distnc); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(17, $tempe); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(18, $pista); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(19, $estpista); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(20, $hora); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(21, $nrocarrr2); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
$hacerConsulta->bindParam(22, $oficial2); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.

if ($hacerConsulta->execute()) {
        echo "<font color=blue>Inserción de la Nueva Carrera fue exitosa</font> <br>";
        $id = $conn->lastInsertId();
} else {
    echo "<font color=blue>Un error ocurrió en la Inserción de la Nueva Carrera</font> <br>";; // Se ejecuta la consulta.
}
```

echo " idcarrera insertado $id  
  ";

```
$hacerConsulta->closeCursor(); // Se libera el recurso.
```

El if entra en forma correcta, el insert se hace, y si lo pongo fuera del if es lo mismo

He probado de muchas maneras y ninguna me funciona

Les agradezco si me pueden ayudar

Comment: No veo que muestres la variable `$id` ¿Cuál es el resultado del código? Puedes depurar con un `var_dump($id);`

Comment: Perdone, pensé que lo había puesto, el valor que muestra es 0 (Cero)

Comment: Cuando pongas código muestra el contexto real. En el código actual no se ve dónde muestras la variable `$id`. En ese contexto no verás nunca el resultado porque no imprimes la variable. Por favor pulsa en [edit] y pon el código real y dinos en qué parte del `if` entra.

Comment: Ahi lo edite para que lo pueda ver, y modifique el comentario

Comment: Acá le pongo lo que muestra el var_dump                                                                               Inserción de la Nueva Carrera fue exitosa
string(1) "0" idcarrera insertado 0

Comment: Pero, ¿esa tabla tiene realmente una columna `AUTOINCREMENT`? `lastInsertId()` sólo devuelve el último ID cuando la tabla tiene columna `AUTOINCREMENT`. Lo puedes verificar ejecutando un `SHOW CREATE TABLE turf_carrr;` directamente en el manejador de base de datos. Te arrojará la composición de la tabla actualmente.

Comment: Tiene razón, voy a revisarlo porque es muy raro esto

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias